# How should I investigate strange behaviour of a Python script in various machines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, debugging, pygsheets

I have written a Python3 script to scrape covid19 data from various websites, do some processing and publish it to Google spreadsheets. I have tested the code thoroughly on my machine and it was working as expected. The Python3 script was supposed to run as a cron job on a remote server, every day at a fixed time. However, when I ran the code on the remote server I am not getting the output as expected.

**Expected output** *(when run from local machine)*: The columns in the Google spreadsheet should be in a particular order.

**Actual output** *(from the remote server)*: The columns in the Google spreadsheet was sorted alphabetically.

I have ensured that the Python3 was used and was updated to the latest available version (3.6.9). The issue still persists.

If it may help, the following are the Python libraries I have used.

pandas==1.0.3

requests==2.23.0

numpy==1.18.1

pygsheets==2.0.3.1

beautifulsoup4==4.9.1

I am quite new to software development and I do not know from where to start investigating such issues.

Comment: I would first ensure that you are 110% certain you are running the same script. Then make sure that running the script at different times does not cause the error. Then check that the data is not the same, but just out of order.

People will be able to help you more if you post your script.

Comment: Generally, Python has a debugger and the "logging" module for writing out log information.